# Select only next div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a Rails app with a list, and each list item has details about that item in a div like this:

```
<ul>
 <% @procedures.each do |procedure| %>
 <li class="proc-names">
  <%= link_to procedure.apc %>
 </li>

 <div class="proc-stats">
  <% @all_procedures = Procedure.where("apc = ?", procedure.apc) %>

  <% avg_charges = 0 %>
  <% avg_payments = 0 %>

<% @all_procedures.each do |pr| %>
    <% avg_charges += pr.avg_submitted_charges.to_i %>
    <% avg_payments += pr.avg_total_payments.to_i %>
<% end %>

National average submitted charges: $<%= number_with_delimiter(avg_charges, delimiter: ',') %><br>
National average total payments: $<%= number_with_delimiter(avg_payments, delimiter: ',') %><br>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make it so that when the link is clicked, it only shows the details (.proc-stats) for that item. This is the jQuery code I have so far, but right now when one link is clicked it shows the details for every list item. Suggestions?

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.proc-names').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('.proc-stats').slideToggle()
```

Comment: Very invalid markup. You can't put `<div>`s directly inside `<ul>`s.

Comment: That's what `$('.proc-stats').slideToggle()` does. You need to find the right `.proc-stats` element relative to your current `.proc-name`.

Comment: @meagar "improper", meh, maybe, but I beg to differ on the later statement you made. http://jsfiddle.net/AjYsC/  And just for more fun http://jsfiddle.net/AjYsC/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently selecing *all* `.proc-stats`.

Instead, you need to find the next `.proc-stats`, relative to the `.proc-names` which was clicked. There's a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Limit your search to the shared [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of the currently clicked `proc-names`:

   ```
   $(document).ready ->
     $('.proc-names').click (event) ->
       event.preventDefault()
       $(this).parent().find('.proc-stats').slideToggle()
   ```
2. Find the currently clicked `.proc-names`'s [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) `.proc-stats`:

   ```
   $(document).ready ->
     $('.proc-names').click (event) ->
       event.preventDefault()
       $(this).next('.proc-stats').slideToggle()
   ```
3. Fix your markup so that your `.proc-stats` is contained within the `.proc-name`, so that your markup is valid, and then find the `.proc-stats` *within* the click `.proc-name`:

   ```
   $(document).ready ->
     $('.proc-names').click (event) ->
       event.preventDefault()
       $(this).find('.proc-stats').slideToggle()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used the third method and refactored my html.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.proc-names').click (event)
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).next('.proc-stats').slideToggle()
```

Change the HTML though:-

```
<ul>
 <% @procedures.each do |procedure| %>
 <li class="proc-names">
  <%= link_to procedure.apc %>
<div class="proc-stats">
  <% @all_procedures = Procedure.where("apc = ?", procedure.apc) %>

  <% avg_charges = 0 %>
  <% avg_payments = 0 %>

<% @all_procedures.each do |pr| %>
    <% avg_charges += pr.avg_submitted_charges.to_i %>
    <% avg_payments += pr.avg_total_payments.to_i %>
<% end %>

National average submitted charges: $<%= number_with_delimiter(avg_charges, delimiter: ',') %><br>
National average total payments: $<%= number_with_delimiter(avg_payments, delimiter: ',') %><br>
  </div>
  <% end %>
 </li>


</ul>
```

Use below for the changed HTML:-

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.proc-names').click (event)
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).find('.proc-stats').slideToggle()
```